# Importing a MySQL database with a Python script fails when the same command works on the command line, what gives?

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I'm running a MySQL server in docker container and am trying to import a .sql file in a Python script (Flask app). This is my code:

```
os.system("docker exec -i %s_db_1 mysql -u<username> -p<password> <db name> < %s" % (name, db_file))
```

It returns this error in the terminal the Flask app is running in:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1835: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

If I run this command from the command line, it works. I can't really figure out how using os.system in this instance is meaningfully different. I've also tried subprocess.call and it produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL request is not well formatted, are you sure it works on command line ?

You should try:

```
os.system("docker exec -i {0}_db_1 mysql -u {1} -p {2} {3}".format(db_file, username, password, db_name))
```

Comment: The <username>, <password>, and <db name> were just placeholders where I removed what was actually being output. The only actual python placeholders are for the name of the container and the name of the file containing the sql dump. If I copy and paste my statement to a command line and put in the appropriate values, it works.

Also, your fix leaves off the actual import of the file. My only guess is that os.system doesn't process the < in the same way that the command line does, but the error isn't consistent with that guess.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NamedTemporaryFile and it turns out that the file wasn't finished writing to disk when I was trying to use it. If I call db_file.flush() right before os.system everything works.